# 日本の人口が少ないです. adjective and noun in this sentence

Tags: grammar

日本の人口が少ないです。 when we define a subject 日本の人口, after the ga particle should there be always a adjective like 少ない for eg...     can we place also place a noun ?

Answer (score 2):

You name, it. It could be a noun, or a verb at least (or adverb(?)).

Noun: わだいになりました (became a (hot) topic)
Verb: へっています (is decreasing)
Adverb(?): ゆっくりへっています (is slowly decreasing)

p.s. I'm glad you are studying Japanese, I hope you work on it + progress!